# Safari Extension Popover access innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, popover, safari-extension

I'm currently developing a Safari Extension, which should search newspaper articles for country or location names. For that, I'd like to search the innerHTML of the current website on which I am. My extension consists of a button in my task bar, which toggles a popover that should show a list of the countries/locations mentioned in an article and a map on which those places are marked.

The problem is that I have no clue how to access the innerHTML in **search.js**.
I'd like to search the innerHTML for specific strings, e.g. "Germany". The apple documentation is not really clear on how to access the website content from an extension. Or how to access anything once one got an safari.application.activeBrowserWindow object.
[Safari Extensions Development Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/ExtensionsOverview/ExtensionsOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH15-SW6)

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

This is my code so far:

### popover.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <link href="popover.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>popover</title>
</head>
<script src="nameSearch.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="locationList">
        <ul id="resultList"></ul>
    </div>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="map.js"></script>
</html>
```

### globalPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Global Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var countriesDE = ['Odessa'];
        var results = ['Germany'];
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

### nameSearch.js

```
const myGlobal = safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow;
myGlobal.results.push(safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.page.innerHTML);

if (document.documentElement.lang.indexOf("de") != -1) {
    for (i = 0; i < myGlobal.countriesDE.length; i++) {
        if (safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.innerHTML.indexOf(myGlobal.countriesDE[i])  != -1) {
            myGlobal.results.push(myGlobal.countriesDE[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

### map.js

```
const myGlobal = safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow;
var ul = document.getElementById("resultList");

for (i = 0; i < myGlobal.results.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myGlobal.results[i]));
    li.setAttribute("id", myGlobal.results[i]);
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["geochart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Popularity'],
        ['Germany', 200] // This is only a test
    ]);

    var options = {};

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('map'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [inject a script](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH6-SW1) into a web page if you want to access its DOM.

Comment: Thanks! I've had the same idea yesterday lying in bed after posting this :D I will try it out and post the solution here.